# lenovo Ideapad application crashed when loading facebook.com in webview

Tags: android, facebook, sqlite, android-webview, android-sqlite

application crashed when loading **facebook.com** in my webview on **lenovo IdeaPadwith** following exception

this is not from my application but exception thrown by the system.

same crash is observed when facebook is loaded in standard browser proviced by lenovo.

After this crashed when I ran the application no crash is observed and able to load facebook page but this is random behavior because I could see crash more than once on standard browser and my webview

is this exception be handled from my application ? how ?

usually this exception is thrown when `onPageFinished()` of webview is getting called but some times its thrown `onPageStarted()`

Following is the logcat log

```
E/MediaProvider(4671): failed to open database external.db
E/MediaProvider(4671):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: error code 5: database is locked 
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_1x1_string(Native Method)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForString(SQLiteStatement.java:154)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:736)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:724)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setJournalMode(SQLiteDatabase.java:1030)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:966)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:734)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider$DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(MediaProvider.java:252)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.query(MediaProvider.java:1743)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:179)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:111)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
E/MediaProvider(4671):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm(121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2041K, 46% free 15375K/28227K, paused 3ms+8ms
W/InputManagerService(121): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4693 uid 10089
D/AsyncChannel(121): TODO: handle sendMessage RemoteExceptionandroid.os.DeadObjectException
D/dalvikvm(4671): GC_EXPLICIT freed 282K, 30% free 6356K/8963K, paused 6ms+2ms
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db' 
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1980)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:977)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:734)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider$DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(MediaProvider.java:252)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.query(MediaProvider.java:1743)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:179)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:111)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db' 
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1980)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:977)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:734)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider$DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(MediaProvider.java:252)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.query(MediaProvider.java:1743)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.attachVolume(MediaProvider.java:4035)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.onCreate(MediaProvider.java:443)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:955)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3880)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3635)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3591)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:122)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1040)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(4671):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
```

Comment: I also got the same exception and std webbrowser is crashed

I am not calling facebook from my own application but with intent I am  staring browser for facebook